# Insert a PHP variable inside Curl

Tags: php, curl

I have that Curl command works fine

```
$ch = curl_init('http://api.pushingbox.com/pushingbox?devid=vB9C6311111098CB&sensor=DELTA&temperature=23');
curl_exec ($ch);

curl_close ($ch);
```

But I need to change the values "DELTA" and "23" with PHP variables `$sensor` and `$temperature`.

My question is: How to insert the variables $sensor and $temperature inside the Curl command?

Answer (score 1):

You can simply concatenate those values like:

```
$delta = "your value";
$temp = 23;

$url = 'http://api.pushingbox.com/pushingbox?devid=vB9C6311111098CB&sensor=' . $delta . '&temperature=' . $temp;

// or 
// $url = "http://api.pushingbox.com/pushingbox?devid=vB9C6311111098CB&sensor=$delta&temperature=$temp";

$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_exec ($ch);

curl_close ($ch);
```

Comment: Could you please indicated what went wrong so we can help you?

Comment: Using the two examples, don't send the message. I don't know why

Comment: If the mounted url is the same as you were using before it has to work. If it's not working you're doing something wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Your CURL command is a string. There are several ways to parse variables into a string.

Using Double Quotes:

`$ch = curl_init("http://api.pushingbox.com/pushingbox?devid=vB9C6311111098CB&sensor=$sensor&temperature=$temperature");`

and

Concatentation:

`$ch = curl_init('http://api.pushingbox.com/pushingbox?devid=vB9C6311111098CB&sensor='.$sensor.'&temperature='.$temperature);`

Are probably the most common.